# Converting rows to wide columns based on duplicated ids in another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, melt

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025752/pivot-duplicates-rows-into-new-columns-pandas), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764983/pandas-pivoting-with-duplicate-values), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927220/how-to-move-duplicate-rows-into-columns-with-python) questions.

But still cannot resolve it.

I have a dataframe with duplicated ids

```
ID  Publication_type
1   Journal          
1   Clinical study   
1   Guideline        
2   Journal          
2   Letter
```

I want to make it wide, but I do not know how many publication type will I have - maybe 2, maybe 20. Thus, I do not know how many columns wide will I need. The max size of wide columns for `publication_type` must be not be more than the number of types for each id.

Expected output

```
 ID Publication_type1 Publication_type2 Publication_type 3    etc
 1  Journal           Clinical Study    Guideline
 2  Journal           Letter            NaN
```

For now I do not need to put the same publication type into the same column. I do not need all articles in the same column. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `ID`, aggregate via `list`, and then create a new DataFrame from the results:

```
col = 'Publication_type'
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('ID')[col].agg(lambda x: x.tolist()).tolist()).replace({None: np.nan})
new_df.columns = [f'{col}{i}' for i in new_df.columns + 1]
new_df['ID'] = df['ID'].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Publication_type1 Publication_type2 Publication_type3  ID
0           Journal    Clinical-study         Guideline   1
1           Journal            Letter               NaN   2
```

Comment: thanks, but the `id` column disappeared :). and there is a small typo in the last line - df, not d. How to preserve the `id`? Thanks!

Comment: Check now @Anakin - I added another line that should work for you ;)